# Unable to get Traefik to proxy local domain without port

Tags: docker, traefik

I have traefik setup on a virtual server on my network (192.168.1.41). I'm trying to proxy multiple local services so they're available on `*.local`. My internal DNS points `*.local` to `192.168.1.41`.

With the following docker-compose.yml:

```
---
version: "2"
services:
  homer:
    image: b4bz/homer
    #To build from source, comment previous line and uncomment below
    #build: .
    container_name: homer
    volumes:
      - /home/mbell/homer/assets/:/www/assets
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    #environment:
    #  - UID=1000
    #  - GID=1000
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.homer.rule=(`dashboard.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.homer.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.homer.loadbalancer.server.port=8081"
    networks:
      - web
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

I think I'm write in assuming that it should run as `dashboard.local` but it only works on `dashboard.local:8081`

How do I make it work so it's only available on `dashboard.local`?

Comment: "Without a port in the URL" actually means "using the default port for the protocol"; port 80 for unencrypted HTTP, port 443 for secure HTTP/TLS.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
"traefik.http.routers.homer.rule=(`dashboard.local`)"
```

Should be:

```
"traefik.http.routers.homer.rule=Host(`dashboard.local`)"
```